# How do I prevent graphics from rescaling when rotating it?

Tags: plotting, graphics

When I use my mouse to rotate the graphics that I plotted to get a better view, it always changes in size, and the axes go all over the place, it impedes my ability to keep track of anything. How do I prevent this?

Edit: For example, if I plot a sphere and rotate it, it can change greatly in size, sometimes even more drastic than the one shown. And the axes change as well, making it hard to discern. I want to fix the image size and axes.  [image]

Comment: May be you can try `SphericalRegion -> True` ? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalRegion.html

Comment: Can you supply a quick example?

Comment: @Nasser I think the SphericalRegion worked, it stopped the constant rescaling and the shifting of the axes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glad it worked. Converting comment to answer

Using `SphericalRegion -> True` will fix the issue

Reference

[reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalRegion.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalRegion.html)